# How to write a library that support both HW and SW Serial communication and allow user to chose which one to use?

Tags: serial, library, softwareserial

I'm working on a library for Arduino/ESP8266/Teensy that use serial to send AT commands. I want to make it as customizable as possible, so I avoided to hardcode the serial and I ask for a reference in the startup method:

```
void MyClass::init(HardwareSerial* hwSerialPtr)
{
   _serialPtr = hwSerialPtr;
   ...
}
```

On some devices, it will be useful to use `SoftwareSerial` instead of the HW one, due to only one serial is available and so keep it for debugging purposes or other features.

So my question is: how can I accept both types? I read both HW and SW serial have `Stream` as base-clase, but it does not have methods like `begin()` etc.

A possible solution I though is so have two pointers (one for HWSerial and one for SWSerial) then wrap some methods like `begin()`, `println()`, `...` in my class and, ond the base of which pointer has been set, use one or the other.

Something like this:

```
class MyClass{
   public:
      void init(HardwareSerial* hwSerialPtr);
      void init(SoftwareSerial* swSerialPtr);

   private:
      HardwareSerial* _hwSerialPtr;
      SoftwareSerial* _swSerialPtr;

      void begin(long baud);
      void println(const String &s)
};
```

then

```
void MyClass::begin(long baud)
{
   if( _hwSerialPtr != null ){ _hwSerialPtr->begin(baudrate); }
   else if( _swSerialPtr != null ){ _swSerialPtr->begin(baudrate); }
}

...etc...
```

but this solution seems to me very tricky and not optimized.

Any better ideas?

Comment: and the way WiFiEsp library examples use is not good?  https://github.com/bportaluri/WiFiEsp/blob/master/examples/WebClient/WebClient.ino

Comment: why do you want to handle begin in the library? and alternative software serial implementations exist

Answer (score 6):

The trick here is to go "up a level".  Both `HardwareSerial` and `SoftwareSerial` inherit from the `Stream` class.  It is *that* class that provides the majority of the interface that you actually use.

So you can provide a constructor with a `Stream` object alone and use that:

```
class Foo {
    private:
        Stream *_dev;

    public:
        foo(Stream *dev) : _dev(dev) {}
        foo(Stream &dev) : _dev(&dev) {}

        void begin() {
            _dev->println("I am ready");
        }
};


Foo myFoo(Serial1);
SoftareSerial btSerial(11,12);
Foo myOtherFoo(btSerial);
```

What the `Stream` class *doesn't* provide, though, is `.begin()` for setting the baud rate. It has to be left to the user to configure the port before using it.

```
Serial1.begin(115200);
myFoo.begin(); // --> "I am ready" on Serial 1
```

or:

```
btSerial.begin(9600);
myOtherFoo.begin(); // --> "I am ready" on Software serial pins 11/12.
```

This is known as *polymorphism*, where an object is seen as one of the parent classes in the inheritance chain and is one of the most powerful aspects of object-oriented programming.

Not having `begin` in your library is no big deal really. It increases the flexibility (a user can more easily select their baud rate), and it means you don't force them to include SoftwareSerial if they don't need it.

There are other things that inherit `Stream`, as well, such as a networking `Client`. So instantly you class can be used with network connections as well as just serial.

So stick to using `Stream`. It's the accepted way of doing things, and perfectly normal. For example, it's how my [ICSC library](https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/ICSC/blob/master/src/ICSC.h) handles serial objects.  (I used to use the multiple pointer method, but it really really got messy when trying to support other platforms. I ended up with `HardwareSerial`, `SoftwareSerial`, `USBSerial`, `Client`... a real mess. So much simpler to just use `Stream`.)

---

BTW, before you ask, I have two constructors with very slight differences so that you can construct an object either by passing a Stream object by reference (as I do in the examples) or as a pointer (which can be great if you want to use this in another class which itself has a pointer to a Stream object).

---

Another option is to combine the Stream pointer with a `dynamic_cast` to try and identify the type of object being passed.

```
void Foo::begin(int baud) {
    if (HardwareSerial *hs = dynamic_cast<HardwareSerial *>(_dev)) {
        hs->begin(baud);
    } else if (SoftwareSerial *ss = dynamic_cast<SoftwareSerial *>(_dev)) {
        ss->begin(baud);
    } else { 
        // We don't know what to do here
        // so do nothing?
    }
}
```

In this way `dynamic_cast` is being used like Java's `instanceof` operator to work out what kind of object it is that is being used.

Of course, that then means that you're really restricting the library to only working with those two types of object, but it is still possible to pass other class types as long as the user pre-configures them before calling your begin function. Which gets confusing - which type does the user need to `.begin()` and which types have `.begin()` called for you? It's just cleaner to always have it as the user must call `.begin()` themselves - there's no ambiguity then.

Answer (score 1):

I second Majenko's advice: inherit from `Stream` and let the user handle
the call to `begin()` if at all possible. However, if you really insist
in calling `begin()` from your class, then I suggest you make your class
a template, like this:

```
// T is the type of the serial port, typically HardwareSerial or
// SoftwareSerial.
template<class T> class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass(T& port) : port(port) {}
        void begin(unsigned long baud) { port.begin(baud); }
    private:
        T& port;
};
```

Your user would then instantiate it as

```
MyClass<HardwareSerial> myObject(Serial);
MyClass<SoftwareSerial> myOtherObject(mySerial);
```

Of course, it doesn't look nice, and it may confuse your users, but it
has the advantage that it can work with anything that remotely looks
like `HardwareSerial`, e.g. `AltSoftSerial` or other alternative
software serial implementations.